# routerLink with url segment not working in angular 8

Tags: angular

Here is my code:

```
<span *ngIf="markup.baseline">   
   <mat-icon [routerLink]="['/default-markup', markup.id]">edit</mat-icon>
 </span>
 <span *ngIf="markup.baseline == 0">   
   <mat-icon [routerLink]="[markup.id]">edit</mat-icon>
 </span>
```

The first link where the url has to be 'default-markup/14' doesnt work.
It  works correctly for the second condition.

The error is

```
core.js:6014 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'default-markup/14
```

Here is the code in the routing module:

```
      {path: ':client', component: MarkupsListComponent, },
      {path: ':client/default-markup', component: MarkupsBaselineComponent,},
      {path: ':client/default-markup/:rule_id', component: MarkupsBaselineComponent,},
      {path: ':client/:rule_id', component: MarkupsDetailComponent,},
```

Comment: what appears in the URL when you click `[routerLink]="[markup.id]"` link?

Comment: My current page url is markups/brookshuff. When I click on [markup.id], it goes to markups/brookshuff/12. I want that for the other condition it should go to markups/brookshuff/default-markup/14

Comment: Just try removing `/` before `default-markup`. Try `[routerLink]="['default-markup', markup.id]"`

Comment: Added answer. Please check, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove `/` before the `/default-markup`. When you mention `/` in the URL, it consider it from the root route, otherwise it will be relative to current route.

Use below

```
[routerLink]="['default-markup', markup.id]"
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to pass client id for every route change it  like this,

```
<span *ngIf="markup.baseline">   
  <mat-icon [routerLink]="['/', clientId,'default-markup',markup.id]>edit</mat-icon>
</span>
<span *ngIf="markup.baseline == 0">   
  <mat-icon [routerLink]="[clientId]">edit</mat-icon>
</span>
```

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routing-child-routes-dn5ahr?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)